# iOS: Accessibility Label for CALayer

Tags: ios, accessibility, calayer

I want to add accessibilityLabel for some of my CALayer's.
Here is the example:

```
CALayer *testLayer = [CALayer layer];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:testLayer];
testLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
testLayer.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
testLayer.accessibilityLabel = @"Some text";
testLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 100, 100);
```

This approach doesn't work for me. Is it possible to make accessibility working for CALayers?
I don't want to use accessibility container in superview (there is complex hierarchy)

Thank you!

Comment: For those willing to use UIAccessibilityContainer, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16428713/1804403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, A custom view built from CALayers does not have support for accessibility so I guess simple answer to your question would be no! You might want to check [Apple's guidelines to create Accessibility for Dynamic Elements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW5).